# Background Bluetooth(BLE) Transmit and Scan

Tags: swift, core-location, core-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

Code works great when the application is open(foreground) but, It does not run in the background. I have all background modes enabled. I have also added Background location updates using .allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates implemented. Not sure where to go from here. Code is below:

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreLocation
 import CoreBluetooth

 class iDevice: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var device: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var deviceImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!

var beaconRegion : CLBeaconRegion!
var beaconPeripheralData : NSDictionary!
var peripheralManager : CBPeripheralManager!

var locationManager : CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initBeaconRegion()
    initTransmit()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager.init()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

    startScanningForBeaconRegion(beaconRegion: getBeaconRegion())

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad) {
        self.device.text = "iPhone"
        self.deviceImg.image =  UIImage(named: "phone")!

    }

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone) {
        self.device.text = "iPad"
        self.deviceImg.image =  UIImage(named: "ipad")!
    }

}

func initTransmit(){
    beaconPeripheralData = beaconRegion .peripheralData(withMeasuredPower: nil)
    peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}
func initBeaconRegion() {
    beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion.init(proximityUUID: UUID.init(uuidString: "E06F95E4-FCFC-42C6-B4F8-F6BAE87EA1A0")!,
                                       major: 1233,
                                       minor: 45,
                                       identifier: "com.peard.idevices")
}
   func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    if (peripheral.state == .poweredOn) {
        peripheralManager .startAdvertising(beaconPeripheralData as? [String : Any])
        print("Powered On")

    } else {
        peripheralManager .stopAdvertising()
        print("Not Powered On, or some other error")
    }
}

func getBeaconRegion() -> CLBeaconRegion {
    let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion.init(proximityUUID: UUID.init(uuidString: "E06F95E4-FCFC-42C6-B4F8-F6BAE87EA1A0")!, identifier: "com.peard.idevices")
    return beaconRegion
}

func startScanningForBeaconRegion(beaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print(beaconRegion)
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)

    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let beacon = beacons.last

    if beacons.count > 0 {

        if beacon?.proximity == CLProximity.unknown {
            distance.text = "Unknown"

        } else if beacon?.proximity == CLProximity.immediate {
            distance.text = "within 3ft"

        } else if beacon?.proximity == CLProximity.near {
           distance.text = "within 5ft"

        } else if beacon?.proximity == CLProximity.far {
            distance.text = "within 20 ft"

        }

    } else {
        print("no")
    }

    print("Ranging")
}


override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent}
@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) { self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

}

Thank you in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your peripheral advertisement behaviour is different when it is in the background mode:-

1. **CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey** advertisement key is ignored and local name of peripheral is not advertised.
2. All service UUIDS contained in value of **CBAdvertismentDataServiceUUIDS** advertisement key are placed in special *overflow area*. They can be discovered only by iOS device explicitly scanning for them.
3. If all apps are advertising then frequency of advertisment packet decreases.

I think you are having 2nd problem.For more details see [Apple programming guide for background processing with core bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Most specifically an iOS device cannot advertise as an iBeacon in the background due to #2